# How can I make sure the picture I inserted in latex to be where i want it to be?

Tags: floats, diagrams

I'm writing a paper on Overleaf and I inserted a picture to explain a definition. But it somehow doesn't show on the page where I want it to be. It always shows on the last page of my paper. Please help.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{convex_hull.jpg}
\caption{Convex hull in $\mathbb{R}^2$}
\label{fig:Convex Hull}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It is in your best interest that you provide a minimal working example.

Comment: `\includegraphics` is positioned like a letter and never moves, other than taking part in line and page breaking like a letter. The _only_ reason to use `figure` environment is to mark the region as a float which may be moved. using `[h]`  means you allow it to move but don't allow it at top bottom or on a page on its own (as you omitted t b p)  so it is quite likely to go to the end of the document.

Comment: So what can I do to fix it?

Comment: see the link I gave, or just simply remove the `figure` environment if you want a non floating image.

Comment: I tried some of them but none of them worked. That's why i'm asking again.